# Importing a OSGi service that is a singleton bean (that has a factory method)

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

**How do I import the exported OSGi service that's a Singleton bean?**

I end up getting the Exception as follows:

```
Unable to start blueprint container for bundle opaClient
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to find a matching constructor on class com.opa.gateway.OPAGateway for arguments [] when instantiating bean opaGateway
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:336)
```

---

**My Blueprint xml where the service is exported is as follows:**

```
<bean id="opaGateway" class="com.opa.gateway.OPAGateway" factory-method="getInstance"/>
<service ref="opaGateway" interface="com.opa.gateway.IOPAGateway" />
```

**And the service is referenced in another bundle as follows:**

```
<reference interface="com.opa.gateway.OPAGateway" component-name="opaGateway" availability="mandatory" />
```

Is there a way to directly reference a singleton bean that's a OSGi service?

Comment: Is there a chance that getInstance function is not static or it has parameters?

Comment: The file is a java project that's bundled as a jar, which I convert as a bundle for my purpose.Though I can write a wrapper class that has getter and setters which returns 'getInstance() of that object' , I wanted to know if there is a way to implement this.

Comment: Ok. But the question is: Does com.scb.opa.gateway.OPAGateway.getInstance(...) take any arguments? Is it a static function? You can pass arguments if necessary and you can call non-static function as well as factory-method but in both cases you must change the blueprint fragment a bit. That is why I am asking.

Comment: Hi @BalazsZsoldos Thank you for the response. It's a no-arg method. Can you please post the answer with brief explanation on it? If you have written a post on it, it would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can reference a singleton which is an OSGi service. Make sure (as @Balazs suggested) that your class has a static function/method `getInstance()`  with no arguments.

Have a look at the blueprint below. Hope it gives you a clue... (If you need the complete sample I can try to post it.

```
<bean   id="opaGateway"
        class="org.test.OPAGateway" factory-method="getInstance">
</bean>

<bean id="opaClient"
      class="org.test.client.OPAClient"
        init-method="startup"
        destroy-method="shutdown">
</bean>

<service ref="opaGateway" interface="org.test.IOPAGateway" />


<reference interface="org.test.IOPAGateway" availability="optional">
    <reference-listener bind-method="setOPAGateway"
                    unbind-method="unsetOPAGateway">
        <ref component-id="opaClient"/>
    </reference-listener>
</reference>
```

- bean opaGateway (org.test.OPAGateway). It is a class implementing `org.test.IOPAGateway`. It is instantiated by static method `getInstance()`:

  ```
  public class OPAGateway implements IOPAGateway {
      private static OPAGateway instance = null;

      public static OPAGateway getInstance () {
          if(instance == null) {
              instance = new OPAGateway();
          }
          return instance;
      }

      // A very simple method...
      @Override
      public String printMessage() {
          return "I AM AN OPAGATEWAY";
      }
  }
  ```
- bean: opaClient: It is just a consumer or the class that references the opaGateway:

  ```
  public class OPAClient {
      public void setOPAGateway(IOPAGateway c) {
          if(c != null) {
              System.out.println("Message: " + c.printMessage());
          }
      }
      public void unsetOPAGateway(IOPAGateway c) {

      }
  }
  ```
- The reference-listener: Injects the instance of `opaGateway` in the `opaClient` using the bind/unbind-method.

You can find more information here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-osgiblueprint/

Comment: Hi @Jorge . Thank you for the response :). Can you describe in brief on the code? I'm not sure about the opaClient you have written. If you can explain, the reference-listener is new to me and is that the one making the difference of solution?

Comment: I have added a brief description of the code above. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I'm yet to implement and try this but looks like this is the solution I look for. Thank you :)